# Locale in Routing, Default Language also without Parameter

Tags: annotations, symfony

I want to define the page language via url on a Symfony2 installation. My routing works via annotation inside the controller.

routing.yml

```
_index:
    resource: "@MyMainBundle/Controller/SiteController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

siteController.php

```
/**
 * @Route( "/{_locale}/{site}", name="_site_site", defaults={"_locale" = "en"}, requirements={"site" = "about|cities|download|blog", "_locale" = "en|de|fr|es"} )
 */
```

This works quiet well, but waht I want, is that the following url call the same action.

```
http://example.com/download
http://example.com/en/download
http://example.com/de/download
```

Without the languge-parameter, the page should switch back to the default language, but this is something I can handle inside my action.

I found this Answer, but could not get it to work at all.
[Symfony2 default locale in routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903477/symfony2-default-locale-in-routing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add another `@Route` annotation that does not include the locale.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/{site}/")
 * @Route("/{site}/")
 */
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add 'defaults={"_locale"="en"}', otherwise it leads to an error, if no locale is found in the url.

Comment: you can add locale in routing.yml after type="annotation"       requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

Answer (score 3):

This also works within annotations.yaml

```
frontend_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Frontend
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        - /
        - /{_locale}
    defaults:
        _locale: 'en'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simular solution for Symfony 5 that worked for me :

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        fr: ''
        en: '/en'
```

Symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have an api prefix you can use next config

```
controllers:
resource: ../../src/Controller/
type: annotation
prefix:
    - api
    - api/{_locale}
defaults:
        _locale: en
```