# Add locale and requirements to all routes - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation

I created an application which was not intended to have translations, but now I decided to add this feature. The problem is that all my routes look like this:

```
goodbye:
    pattern: /goodbye
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Goodbye:goodbye }
```

and I want them now to be like this:

```
goodbye:
    pattern: /goodbye/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Goodbye:goodbye, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|bg
```

Do I really have to do this and is there a way to do more global or automatic, or at least to add requriements only once, because they are the same for all urls? Thank very much in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [JMS18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) ([documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)) for this purpose. No custom loader, no coding ...

The bundle is able to prefix all your routes with the locale without changing anything except some configuration for the bundle. It's the quickest ( and my recommended ) solution to get you started.

You can even translate existing routes for different locales.

A quick introduction can be found in [this coderwall post](https://coderwall.com/p/eiqd_g).

Comment: This is a good choice if you want to *translate your urls* as well. For instance : */en/buy-a-car* vs */fr/acheter-une-voiture*. Otherwise it's a bit of an overkill in my opinion and using rooting.yml `prefix` option is the way to go.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it this way, in your global configuration file

```
customsite:
  resource: "@CustomSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /{_locale}
  requirements:
    _locale: fr|en
  defaults: { _locale: fr}
```

Quite slow reaction, but had some similar issue.

Nice to know is that you can also drop the {_locale} prefix when importing the resource. You would then be required to add {_locale} to every specific route.

This way you can catch the www.domain.com without a locale from inside your bundle, without having to rewrite the requirements and the defaults.

You could however, always define the www.domain.com route in your global routing configuration.

Comment: I tried exactly like this but it works for me only when locale is specified explicitly in the route. If I write something like: 
http://host/en/controller
I get necessary result.
But if I write
http://host/controller
the route doesn't get "en" locale. Instead Symfony throws NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: Disclaimer: last time I wrote php was around the time of writing this comment, and Symfony2 has gotten quite some updates since then.

What you describe is most likely the expected behavior. The default language is important for when people end up on your homepage (www.example.com). The behavior you want is very difficult to accomplish as it would require symfony to know that the second parameter in your route is a path, rather than a language.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please read questions first. The question was how to avoid adding locale configuration to every route.

Comment: Doesn't this global site-wide configuration prefix all of the actual routes stored in "@CustomSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"? Correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't used php in 5 years.

Answer (score 3):

Configure symfony for localization:

**Add localization to the session(please note that the convention is /locale/action):**

```
goodbye:

    pattern: /{_locale}/goodbye
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Goodbye:goodbye, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|bg
```

**Alternatively locale can be set manually:**

```
$this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'en_US');
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

**In your response:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function indexAction()
{
    $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Symfony2 is great');

    return new Response($translated);
}
```

Configure localization messages localized files:

messages.bg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Symfony2 is great</source>
                <target>Symfony2 е супер</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>symfony2.great</source>
                <target>Symfony2 е супер</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

messages.fr

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Symfony2 is great</source>
                <target>J'aime Symfony2</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>symfony2.great</source>
                <target>J'aime Symfony2</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

More on the topic: [Official symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Comment: The question was how to avoid adding locale configuration to every route.

Answer (score 3):

The better solution instead of putting requirements in all routes or global scope is to use EventListener and redirect user into same route, but with supported locale, in example:

```
<?php

namespace Selly\WebappLandingBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleInParamListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $defaultLocale;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $supportedLocales;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $localeRouteParam;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $defaultLocale = 'en_US', array $supportedLocales = array('en_US'), $localeRouteParam = '_locale')
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        $this->supportedLocales = $supportedLocales;
        $this->localeRouteParam = $localeRouteParam;
    }

    public function isLocaleSupported($locale) {
        return in_array($locale, $this->supportedLocales);
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale = $request->get($this->localeRouteParam);

        if(null !== $locale) {
            $routeName = $request->get('_route');

            if(!$this->isLocaleSupported($locale)) {
                $routeParams = $request->get('_route_params');

                if (!$this->isLocaleSupported($this->defaultLocale))
                    throw \Exception("Default locale is not supported.");

                $routeParams[$this->localeRouteParam] = $this->defaultLocale;
                $url = $this->router->generate($routeName, $routeParams);

                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

And `services.yml`

```
services:
    selly_webapp_landing.listeners.localeInParam_listener:
        class: Selly\WebappLandingBundle\EventListener\LocaleInParamListener
        arguments: [@router, "%kernel.default_locale%", "%locale_supported%"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

In `parameters.yml` you can specify supported locales:

```
locale_supported: ['en_US', 'pl_PL']
```

Comment: I think what you did is what I'm looking for, but can you give me the file names for where you are supposed to put this code? In particular for LocaleInParamListener?

Comment: can we use shortcodes for locale instead of en_US, just en?

Comment: also can you show us what the routes look like with annotations and how its supposed to look? I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a custom loader extending the classic config loader (Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader) and manipulate the pattern

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html

check the first example, i haven't tried it yet, but i'm quite sure it will fit your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168304/6321297

The `{_local}` parameter in route has to be in the app/config routing file if you want to apply it to all your routes.

This solution uses an event listener to redirect to the good url if there is no `{_local}` in the url: 
Change `yoursite.com/your/route` to `yoursite.com/{_locale}/your/route`

It works with or without params.