# Symfony default locale without specifying in URL

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I would like to configure the Symfony `locale` options so that I can successfully access the following routes:

```
/route
/{locale}/route
```

Currently, I can access `/{locale}/route` and I get my view, however, `/route` returns a `No route found for "GET /route"`.  My configuration is as follows:

```
#app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    locale: en

#app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    app_locales: en|fr
framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale: "%locale%"

#app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

My Controller has the following annotations:

```
#src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/MyController.php
/**
 *
 * @Route(
 *     "/{_locale}/admin/my",
 *     defaults={"_locale":"%locale%"},
 *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
 *     )
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_my_list")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I specifically include the `locale`, it all works.  If I exclude the `locale`, I get the `No route found` error.

Comment: I do not think the following pattern is applicable. The `/route` and `/{_locale}/route` are two different routes which are matched based on the requirements of the `_locale` (amongst other) which are defined as `en` or `fr`. When you define the default `_locale` it will only help you when generating routes and omitting the `_locale` parameter. If you really want to do though (and I don't advise it), you may write a custom `RouteMatcher`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define another route to cover the scenario without the provided locale, try changing your route definition to:

```
#src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/MyController.php

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/admin/my",
     *     defaults={"_locale":"%locale%"},
     *     )
     * @Route(
     *     "/{_locale}/admin/my",
     *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
     *     )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out you cannot apply multiple routes at the `Controller` class level, however, I can apply this to the `Action` and it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Boris commented up there.

An alternative solution about making a RouteMatcher is to use EventListener and redirect user into [same route with the default Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610234/add-locale-and-requirements-to-all-routes-symfony2) (Check the answer that has more upvotes)

In my opinion doing this with EventListeners like Athlan explained there is the way to go. I would not mess with making your own RouteMatcher.
Just see what lordrhodos wrote, never tried to put two routes like this in a Controller annotations, but I think if you have only one Controller is the way to go. If they are going to be a lot might be a lot cleaner to do this with EventListeners in only one place.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with:

```php
#[Route(['/{_locale}/{path}', 'en' => '/{path}'], requirements: ['path' => '.*', '_locale' => 'en|fr'])]
```

This is explained at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n

Normally one would use:

```php
'en' => '/en/{path}', 'fr' => '/fr/{path}'
```

But seeing as `{_locale}` gets captured first, and `$request->getLocale()` is set to the locale if you use 'fr' for example, and we just enforce that for the second match for the default locale 'en', which sets the locale from the associative array.