# Symfony2 redirect simple routes to default language

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, routes

How are you doing? I'm developing a multilingual platform with Symfony2. If someone types in www.url.com/project I want to have it redirected to www.url.com/en/project. Whats the easiest way to do so without repeating a method and all the routes a couple of times?

For the main url www.url.com to www.url.com/en/ I use the following controller

```
    public function rootAction(Request $request) {
    $locale = $request -> getLocale();
    return $this -> redirect($this -> generateUrl('dbe_underConstructionLang', array('_locale' => $locale)));
    }
```

And here the routes:
The default:

```
dbe_underConstruction:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: DbeBundle:UnderConstruction:root }
```

This is a default page

```
dbe_aboutus:
    path:     /{_locale}/aboutus
    defaults: { _controller: DbeBundleBundle:Aboutus:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de
```

Furthermore I was not able to make the login route multilingual because in the security.yml I was not able to set the required _locale parameter:

```
dbe_login:
path:     /login
defaults: { _controller: DbeBundle:Login:login}

 firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

Thanks already!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903477/symfony2-default-locale-in-routing),hope you can find some solutions..

Answer (score 1):

For me, best solution is to use [JMSI18RoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). There are some configurations in config.yml and nothing else - no changes in routing.yml.

Comment: Means without this bundle I need to write down all the routes?