# Set default locale with routing in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, localization, routes, internationalization

I configure my main route in `routing.yml` like this:

```
geekhub_main:
resource: "@GeekhubMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /{_locale}
defaults: { _locale: en }
requirements:
    _locale: en|uk
```

As described here [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements), but when I go do the some page without locale, like
`example.com/posts` instead of `example.com/en/posts` I get an error about `No route found for ...`

So what I am doing wrong?

There is a related post here [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903477/symfony2-default-locale-in-routing/25038376#25038376), but I suppose `defaults` way better than `_locale: |en|uk` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation:

> Of course, you can have more than one optional placeholder (e.g.
>   /blog/{slug}/{page}), but everything after an optional placeholder
>   must be optional. For example, /{page}/blog is a valid path, but page
>   will always be required (i.e. simply /blog will not match this route).

If you have `_locale` as a prefix, the router will require that you add it always (even though you added a default value).

If instead of a prefix, your route looked like this:

```
_test:
    path: /test/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:contact, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|uk
```

`/test` would work and `/test/en` would work.

So, using prefixes, I think that the better and more elegant approach would be defining multiple patterns:

```
_test:
  path:   /test
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:contact, _locale: en }

_test_:
  path:   /{_locale}/test
  defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:contact}
  requirements:
      _locale:  en|uk
```

`test` would work and `/en/test` too.

The solution of:

```
requirements:
   _locale:  |en|uk
```

is not a good option due to the fact that `//test` would be a valid URL.

Comment: so how I understand I need to add two variats to each path in routing.yml of each my bundle?

Comment: @excluded_once No, not at all, you can get around that.

Comment: @acontell sorry that I will ask you to remember about this solution but can you tell us how can we avoid going through all routes because I have an application that has hundreds of routes and I can't just go through all of them and set them to use two different variants