# How to set locale router parameter in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I want to determine user locale and set corresponding parameter in router in such a way as to set it into url. I tried to set locale to request object and session on `kernel.request` event, but it always set default locale parameter into url.

I saw needed behaviour in symfony cmf, but haven't found how that implemented. Have read documentation. Have searched for answer. No results.

Comment: Use this bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

or this, depending on what you are after

[Symfony2 default locale in routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903477/symfony2-default-locale-in-routing)