# Quit _locale from url in en language Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, twig, multilingual

I have a project multi language with a `<select>` in all footer pages.
When I'm in pages from my web, the url is like this: `/es/privacy` `/en/privacy`.
Now I want delete the language in specific language, english.

if I'm in privacy page browsing in Spanish `/es/privacy` but if I'm browsing in English `/privacy`.
This is an example of my `routing.yml`:

```
privacy_lang:
 path: /{_locale}/privacy
 defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Documents:privacy }

privacy:
 path: /privacy
 defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Documents:privacy }
```

And this my controller:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/privacy", name="privacy")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function privacyAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/privacy.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
```

Now I have button in my page goes to Privacy Page:

```
<a class="privacy enllac-lower" href="{{ path('privacy_lang') }}">Privacy Policy</a>
```

How can I delete `/en/` when user are browsing in english?
Now if I go to `http://www.myweb.com/privacy` redirects to `http://www.myweb.com/es/privacy`.

Comment: Is using URL rewriting for all URL's with en an option for you ? I mean you'll keep all the logic of your website and multilang intouched, and just add a rule to rewrite `site.ext/en/page` to `site.ext/page`

Comment: Or take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903477/symfony2-default-locale-in-routing